# не получается использовать setInterval вы цикле

Tags: javascript

```
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (i !== arr.length) {
         setInterval(console.log("???"), 1000);
     }
 }
```

вот небольшой код для примера я наверное в коде что-то не попорядку пишу или вобще неправильно, есть массив заданной длины допустим как на примере, задача в том кчтобы консольЛог выводинся через каждую секунду столько раз сколько длина масива! я попробовал в цыкле а он сразу все вывел где у меня ошибка??

Comment: `if (i !== arr.length)` **всегда** `true`, если только ты внутри цикла не будешь изменять `arr`

Comment: ну и передавать надо **функцию** первым параметром `setInterval(function(){...}, 1000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let count = arr.length

const id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("???");
  count--;
  if (count === 0) {
    clearInterval(id);
  }
}, 1000);
```